# typing in Iframe firefox

Tags: iframe, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium Webdriver (the 2nd) in java

I am trying to figure out how to type inside of an IFrame.  Right now, I am:

`WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
Wait<WebDriver> wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("#cke_contents_textarea1 iframe"))).sendKeys("Test Text");`

The html is:
`<td id="cke_contents_textarea1" class="cke_contents" style="height:200px" role="presentation"><iframe style="width: 657px; height: 100%; " frameborder="0" title="Rich text editor, textarea1, press ALT 0 for help." src="" tabindex="-1" allowtransparency="true">
</iframe>
</td>`

I've edited a lot of code out, so I might of missed pasting something in.

I have verified that the cursor appears inside of the text box (and when I select a different iframe, the cursor moves as well)
Is there different code to type in an Iframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer sample code: I have used website contains iFrame.
(Note: you have to make sure in our webpage source code contain(s) iframe)

```
WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
driver.get("http://www.packagemapping.com/example1.htm#.UJS4DFIerb8");

driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.name("frame_track")));
System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='table2']/tbody/tr/td[3]/font")).getText());
driver.findElement(By.name("shipper")).sendKeys("DHL");
```

Answer (score 1):

I am surprised you see the cursor without switching to the Iframe.
Try doing it this way

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.id("frameId")));
//do your stuff
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

Comment: How would I select the element to .sendKeys() to?  I tried the normal way, and it didn't work.

Comment: you can select by `id="cke_contents_textarea1"` to sendKeys too. Also i am pretty sure your textarea filed is not inside the iframe. So simply do `driver.findElement(By.id("cke_contents_textarea1")).sendKeys("Test Text");`

Answer (score 0):

for typing inside the iframe use the following Java code for selenium Webdriver.

driver.switchTo().frame((WebElement)driver.findElement(By.xpath("enter xpath of iframe here")));
driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath of iframe textbox")).sendKeys("testing");
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();

Answer (score 0):

It happens because the element is not  fully loaded.In my case putting Thread.sleep(1000) before sendKeys did the trick.

```
 WebElement iFrameElmnt = cntntPnlFrmWrpr.findElement(By.tagName("iframe"));
            driver.switchTo().frame(iFrameElmnt);
            WebElement inputText = driver.findElement(By.id("__o3id0"));
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            inputText.sendKeys("12344");
```

Comment: `Thread.sleep` is pretty much always a bad idea.  It either waits too long (if the element appears before 1 second), or it waits too short (if the page is still loading after a second).  Use WebDriverWait to wait for an element to appear.